# How to loop a function in if else conditions

Tags: python

Im trying to loop a function in itself in a special condition but as it re runs the function refreshes the variable "j" also. So i want to use that functions repeadetly to check connection and refresh the page so if i put variables to the out of the functions it will run once and makes it top value so the looping second time will fail. How to fix that?

```
def checkConnection():
    onPage = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('onpage.png', grayscale = True, confidence = 0.8)
    noConnectionError = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('noconnection.png', grayscale = True, confidence = 0.8)
    sleep(2)
    if onInstagram != None:
        print("[INFO] : NETWORK STATUS : SUCCESS")
    elif noConnectionError != None:
        print("[WARNING] : NO CONNECTION !!!")
        print("[INFO] TYRING TO RECONNECT...")
        sleep(1)
        j = 0
        while j < 3:
            print("[INFIO] REFRESHING PAGE... TRIAL : "+ str(j+1))
            refresh()
            sleep(3)
            checkConnection()
        print("[WARNING] : TRY AGAIN FAILED")
        sleep(1)
        print("[WARNING] : *****QUIT*****")
        sleep(5)
        quit()
```

Comment: You want to call the function checkConnection() 3 times, before it prints the last warning lines and quits?

Comment: Add `tries=0` as an argument to `checkConnection`. Replace the while-loop with `if triess < 3:`, and then do `checkConnection(tries + 1)` as the recursive call.

Comment: May be you could try passing the value of j as parameter in your function `checkConnection(j)`. Initially it would start with 0 i,e `checkConnection(0)` and then inside the loop use `checkConnection(j+1)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro worked out perfectly thank you. Afsana Khan aswell but couldnt tag him